# How to use pipe in a single quoted sql query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package with code shown like below,

For example when i use this code,

```
SELECT f.ID,(f.source||'-'||A.TITLE) AS source_system FROM T1 f LEFT JOIN T2 a ON f.SOURCE = a.code;
```

im, getting below results,

```
id  source_system 
14  X-Unified
14  R-Clarity
14  G-Complete
14  C-South
14  E-East
```

But, when i use same query in package like shown belo, i'm getting error can anyone help me how to use pipe in single quoted oracle query?

```
SEARCHSQL := 'SELECT ';
SEARCHSQL := SEARCHSQL ||  ' f.id,(f.SOURCE||''-''||a.TITLE) AS source_system FROM T1 f LEFT JOIN T2 a ON f.SOURCE = a.code';
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And can you show how you are using that string? The construction you've shown looks OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE TABLE T1
(
    "SOURCE"   VARCHAR2 (4000),
    "ID"       VARCHAR2 (4000)
);

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    "CODE"    VARCHAR2 (4000),
    "TITLE"   VARCHAR2 (4000)
);

DECLARE
    SEARCHSQL   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    SEARCHSQL := 'SELECT ';
    SEARCHSQL :=
           SEARCHSQL
        || ' f.id,(f.SOURCE||''-''||a.TITLE) AS system FROM T1 f LEFT JOIN T2 a ON f.SOURCE = a.code';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SEARCHSQL);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SEARCHSQL;
END;

DROP TABLE T1;
DROP TABLE T2;
```

Output:

> Table T1 created.
>
> Table T2 created.
>
> SELECT  f.id,(f.SOURCE||'-'||a.TITLE) AS system FROM T1 f LEFT JOIN T2 a ON f.SOURCE = a.code;
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> Table T1 dropped.
>
> Table T2 dropped.